# Multiple senders to single channel in Golang

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

The concept seems simple to explain, but a tad harder to implement ("correctly").

The tl;dr is I want to run multiple functions that push output into a single channel.

As a sample working test (with multiple channels), to elaborate on my question https://play.golang.org/p/1ztCvPFLXKv

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type intTest struct {
    ID     int
    Number int
}

func modify1(channelID string, res chan []intTest) {
    s := []intTest{}
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Adding inside: %s\n", channelID)
        s = append(s, intTest{i, 0})
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    }
    res <- s
}
func modify2(channelID string, res chan []intTest) {
    s := []intTest{}
    for i := 10; i < 20; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Adding inside: %s\n", channelID)
        s = append(s, intTest{i, 0})
        time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond)
    }
    res <- s
}
func modify3(channelID string, res chan []intTest) {
    s := []intTest{}
    for i := 20; i < 30; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Adding inside: %s\n", channelID)
        s = append(s, intTest{i, 0})
        time.Sleep(300 * time.Millisecond)
    }
    res <- s
}

func main() {
    channelA := make(chan []intTest)
    channelB := make(chan []intTest)
    channelC := make(chan []intTest)

    go modify1("A", channelA)
    go modify2("B", channelB)
    go modify3("C", channelC)

    b := append(<-channelA, <-channelB...)
    b = append(b, <-channelC...)
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

**Output:**

```
Adding inside: C
Adding inside: A
Adding inside: B
..snip..
Adding inside: C
Adding inside: C
Adding inside: C
[{0 0} {1 0} {2 0} {3 0} {4 0} {5 0} {6 0} {7 0} {8 0} {9 0} {10 0} {11 0} {12 0} {13 0} {14 0} {15 0} {16 0} {17 0} {18 0} {19 0} {20 0} {21 0} {22 0} {23 0} {24 0} {25 0} {26 0} {27 0} {28 0} {29 0}]
```

However, I would like to achieve something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/qvC88LwkanY
**Output:**

```
Adding inside: C
Adding inside: A
Adding inside: B
..snip
Adding inside: B
Adding inside: A
Adding inside: C
[{0 0} {1 0} {2 0} {3 0} {4 0} {5 0} {6 0} {7 0} {8 0} {9 0}]
```

but as shown the functions modify2 & modify3 visually seems like they never get added.

Is this possible, or is the top sample more feasible?

Comment: If you want them all pushing to the same channel, why not have them all push to the same channel as in the play link?

Comment: Your problem in your second example is that you're only receiving from the channel once, which means only the _first_ sender to the channel (in this case, A, though it's technically non-deterministic) gets received.  If you need output from all 3, you need to receive from the channel 3 times to get all of the output (sending to a channel doesn't just magically concatenate all of those values!)

Comment: Do you want to wait till all the routines are done before printing the results?

Comment: Awesome, I think I might have misunderstood the concept of blocking/sending, according to my brain, by sending to the channel it would all get pulled after the go routines have finished, almost like popping onto a stack and then pulling the whole stack.

But I do understand now that I have to "pull for each push". Thank you very much all :)

Comment: play.golang.org/p/_v1r_cQ5gAS It seems that Body.Close() does not close the go routine.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to achieve something like this

```
channelA := make(chan []intTest)
go modify1("A", channelA)
go modify2("B", channelA)
go modify3("C", channelA)
```

> Is this possible, or is the top sample more feasible?

Yes: you can use a single channel across multiple goroutines -- that's what channels are designed for.

> but as shown the functions modify2 & modify3 visually seems like they never get added.

The problem you have there is that you only called the receive operator once:

```
b := append(<-channelA)
fmt.Println(b)
```

The other two goroutines were either blocked waiting to send their result, or still building their result, when your `main` goroutine exited.

If you change your `main()` function to this, you can see that all three workers will send their results over the channel if another routine is ready to receive (because you used an unbuffered channel, sends will block until a receiver is ready):

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan []intTest)

    go modify1("A", ch)
    go modify2("B", ch)
    go modify3("C", ch)
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Adding inside: C
Adding inside: A
Adding inside: B
Adding inside: A
Adding inside: A
Adding inside: B
Adding inside: C
Adding inside: A
Adding inside: B
Adding inside: A
Adding inside: A
Adding inside: B
Adding inside: C
Adding inside: A
Adding inside: A
Adding inside: B
Adding inside: A
Adding inside: C
Adding inside: A
Adding inside: B
[{0 0} {1 0} {2 0} {3 0} {4 0} {5 0} {6 0} {7 0} {8 0} {9 0}]
Adding inside: C
Adding inside: B
Adding inside: B
Adding inside: C
Adding inside: B
Adding inside: C
Adding inside: B
[{10 0} {11 0} {12 0} {13 0} {14 0} {15 0} {16 0} {17 0} {18 0} {19 0}]
Adding inside: C
Adding inside: C
Adding inside: C
[{20 0} {21 0} {22 0} {23 0} {24 0} {25 0} {26 0} {27 0} {28 0} {29 0}]
```

You can then change that code to append received elements to a single list prior to output, or otherwise format the received elements in whatever way you like.

> I thought it's almost like popping onto a stack and then pulling the whole stack

With an initialized, not-closed, buffered channel, a send statement puts one element onto a queue, and a receive operation pops one element off the queue and returns it.  It's first in first out (FIFO) order, so it's a queue rather than a stack.  In the examples above the channel is unbuffered, so a send has to wait for a goroutine ready to receive, and a receive has to wait for a goroutine ready to send.  Main is a goroutine as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I understand the concept/design you have given...

My understanding of the blocking/sending was a bit skew, I thought it's almost like popping onto a stack and then pulling the whole stack.

Comment: This method is 100% valid, but once applied to an HTTP related function it seems to be hanging, here is a sample of what I'm talking about: https://play.golang.org/p/_v1r_cQ5gAS


It seems that Body.Close() does not close the go routine.

Comment: Why would response.Body.Close() close the goroutine?

Comment: The code you linked in your comment contains an infinite for { ... } loop.  It looks like you only call `os.Exit` on error.  So I don't see why your program wouldn't run forever.

Comment: The code you linked is different code with different issues.  If you want more help with it I suggest you post it as a new question.